# Size of the thumb graphic on a Flash slider

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am able to assign custom design to my Flash slider using `mySlider.setStyle("thumbUpSkin", myThumbUpSkinShape)`. However, this does not set the size of the thumb to the shape I have defined. How do I set the size of the thumb graphic to the exact size of my custom designed shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to change the size of the thumb like this:

```
mySlider.getChildAt(1).width = 100;
mySlider.getChildAt(1).height = 50;
```